# Array will only set values to "0" when writing from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

```
    String path1, path2;
    int count = 0, i = 0;
    path1 = args[0];

    File file = new File(path1);
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(reader);

    while(inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
        inputFile.nextLine();
        count++;
    }
    int[] array1 = new int[count];
    while(inputFile.hasNextInt()) {

        //inputFile.nextLine();
        array1[i] = inputFile.nextInt();
        i++;
    }
```

I never had this issue before, but when I try to write values to an array from a text file containing only int values, one per line, my array only returns all "0"s. instead of the numbers in the text file. I'm not sure if it has to do with me using the command line, but it has the correct argument (file destination) entered in my IDE.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, your int[] will be initialized to 0s. Are you *sure* the second while loop is executing at all? Hint: why would there be a `.nextInt()` if you've already `.nextLine()`'d to the end of the file?

Comment: You completely read the file in the first loop. The second loop doesn't do anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the exit condition of both while loops are the same. If the first ends then the second one will be jumped over as the condition is immediately false. The pointer of the scanner is already at the end of the file (all numbers have been read by the first loop) so there is nothing left to read.

You have 2 options to fix this issue.

1. Use an ArrayList: Use an `ArrayList<int>` object to save the numbers in the first loop. The list grows as numbers are entered so you don't need to know the number of lines before making this object, as opposed to needing to know this to make an array.
2. Scan the file again: In between the loops close the previous filereader and scanner and create a new one. This new scanner will point to the start of the file again and the second loop will run smoothly.